# PHP file upload medical images

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading

I want to upload medical images which is in extension (.nii & .mnc  & . dcm)

I have tried adding the extension in `application/config/mimes.php` but not work, how can I upload medical images which have extension(.nii, .mnc, .dcm)?

```
return array(
    'nii'   =>  array('image/nii'),
    'dcm'   =>  array('image/dcm'),
    '3g2'   =>  'video/3gpp2',
    '3gp'   =>  array('video/3gp', 'video/3gpp'),
    'mp4'   =>  'video/mp4',
    'm4a'   =>  'audio/x-m4a',
    'f4v'   =>  array('video/mp4', 'video/x-f4v'),
    'flv'   =>  'video/x-flv',
    'webm'  =>  'video/webm',
    'aac'   =>  'audio/x-acc',
    'm4u'   =>  'application/vnd.mpegurl',
    'm3u'   =>  'text/plain',
    'xspf'  =>  'application/xspf+xml',
    'vlc'   =>  'application/videolan'
);
```

Comment: and what is the error you are receiving

Comment: format not supported

Comment: Are you sure the files has image/nii or image/dcm mime types?

You can check mimes via ``mime_content_type ( $filename )``

Comment: yea so you would do ^ and make an array like `the_ext => 'some/mime'`

Comment: You must know about the file types.  like jpg file type is image/jpeg.

Comment: Have you tried adding all types on upload? $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

Comment: looks like your extensions are not included here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: During upload are you trying to do any manipulation of the images or even attempting to read exif data? That could cause issues if the file format is not recognized. That said, your upload code would help